# Check if each element of a tensor is contained in a list

Tags: python, pytorch, comparison

Say I have a tensor `A` and a container of values `vals`. Is there a clean way of returning a Boolean tensor of the same shape as `A` with each element being whether that element of `A` is contained within `vals`? e.g:

```py
A = torch.tensor([[1,2,3],
                  [4,5,6]])
vals = [1,5]
```

```py
# Desired output
torch.tensor([[True,False,False],
              [False,True,False]])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply do like this:

```
result = A.apply_(lambda x: x in vals).bool()
```

Then `result` will contain this tensor:

```
tensor([[ True, False, False],
        [False,  True, False]])
```

Here I simply used a lambda function and the apply_ method that you can find in the [official documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html).

Comment: The apply operator with generator only works on CPU tensors

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve this with a for loop:

```py
sum(A==i for i in B).bool()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
[list(map(lambda x: x in vals, thelist)) for thelist in A]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `torch.isin` method is the most convinient way. It's simple as follows: `torch.isin(A, vals)`